# Create Beans in Spring dynamiclly

Tags: java, spring, session, asynchronous

I am using Spring3.1

My application will have kind of bean-manager.

That manager will be able to retrieve request and on each request I need to create new instance of bean dynamically which will be initiate with it's own unique params.

The params will be retrieved via the request method.

This bean must be alive and work asynchronously. (For example it will listen to jms calls, execute methods by demand and so on..)

Moreover I want to have the option to destroy beans also.

Those bean could be resemble as sessions so when the user log off i will destroy those beans.

I understand that I have to create some kind of bean-list or beans pool and manage it with some kind of manager.

How can I create those beans dynamically and have them remain them alive until I destroy them?

Any idea how could I implement such thing?

Comment: Is there a reason they need to be Spring beans? Why not just regular objects in your application?

Comment: Coz I want those object to be participate in the "Spring framework" think about aop/transaction/wiring. also I want to control sessions pool and control the num of instances I dont want to implement all myself..else I wouldnt need Spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in this sense, the easiest way would be to create a `StaticApplicationContext` setting its parent context as the common context (the one holding the beans you want to share over all). This you could reach by doing something like:

```
StaticApplicationContext innerContext = new StaticApplicationContext(parentContext);
```

after this, you probably want to declare the bean you want to instantiate over Spring in order to attach all the AOP stuff, Autowiring and other functionalities, therefore you will need to do something like:

```
innerContext.registerSingleton("beanName", beanClass);
```

After registering you could instantiate the bean like:

```
innerContext.getBean(beanClass);
```

Of course there is the implementation of scope `Session` for spring and therefore I advise you to check the `WebApplicationContext` documentation, method [`loadParentContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html#loadParentContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29) that you basically pass the ServletContext as paramenter.

Comment: Hi, You said I should use prototype. but prototype  is equal to statefull. is my case seems a statefull case? thanks.

Comment: I just commented about prototype because I don't know how you want to store it, if it is in the user's session or so...

Comment: When you say user session  - it is in the user session but it's not through web/http. the user will connect else where via some protocol and I will have to create a new session and manage it until the user log off all by myself.

Comment: I see, I thought a bit more and prototype doesn't make much sense, because it depends on how do you create the `StaticApplicationContext`, if you have it per user you could hold your user-specific beans on that context and terminate it when the session should be finished.

Comment: Could you edit please your answer and show me example? what do you mean hold user-specific beans? I have the same bean for all users just with diffrent states. I have to create new one each time a user logging in and that bean will keep alive and work asynchronously till I Kill it(which will happen when the user logs off)

Comment: I didn't meant that you will have just one bean. What I meant was that you will have one bean (singleton) in each `StaticApplicationContext` context, as you will create one `StaticApplicationContext` per user, you will still have one bean (with specific state) for each user, but singleton on its static context, did you get it?

Comment: I think. and how will I be able to destroy it when the times come? should I save it in a static list or something?

Comment: You would just invoke `StaticApplicationContext.close()`

Comment: you wrote in your example: (this.context. where do I take my context from? let's say i am inside a spring bean. it doest have any context variable.

Comment: this is the spring context that you will share with all... the context that is not user-specific

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13600/discussion-between-rayman-and-francisco-spaeth)

Answer (score 0):

I've also found many trouble in creating a bean dynamically at run-time and used it anywhere in application..

Here is complete code

```
static ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { "Spring-Question.xml" });
    static StaticApplicationContext innerContext = new StaticApplicationContext(appContext);
```

Create the bean and set the values e.g.

```
innerContext.registerSingleton("beanName", Test.class);
        Test test = innerContext.getBean(Test.class);
        test.setA(3);
        test.setB(4);
```

Then Re-Use the bean anywhere in application....

```
Test test = innerContext.getBean(Test.class);
        System.out.println(test.setB(4));
```